# Unable to publish Bot Composer in azure

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I built my bot using Bot Framework Composer 2.1 and everything looked nice in the design process, however, when I was about to publish it I got the following message:

```
Provision failure

{"name":"CREATE_APP_REGISTRATION","message":"App create failed! Please file an issue on Github.","stack":"Error\n at new CustomizeError (\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\dist\\extension.js:269071:25)\n at createCustomizeError (\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\dist\\extension.js:269076:10)\n at BotProjectProvision.createApp (\\resources\\app.asar.unpacked\\extensions\\azurePublish\\dist\\extension.js:270566:17)"}. See provision.botazure.log in your bot folder
```

Anyone happens to know how to sort this issue out?

Comment: Does the bot work when you test it in Composer?

Comment: Yes. When I test it on composer it works.

Comment: Did you create the resources out in Azure yet?  The error sounds like it can't reach your app service.  Have you followed these instructions?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot?tabs=v2x

Comment: I did it, indeed. However, it did not work when choosing "create new resources". As far as I know, the resources are created from scracth through this option. In the end, the only way I sorted this problem out was using the second alternative "import existing resources". Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug and is being tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/8283).